# On an Apple Silicon or T2 Mac: Can you go back to Full Security after changing to Reduced Security and installing System Extensions?

Tags: macos, security, apple-silicon, monterey

I just moved from an Intel Mac (Pre T2 era) to an Apple Silicon Mac and I'm confused about how the new security model/boot sequence actually works. Some software wants me to boot into recovery mode and change the security policy just to load an extension to capture audio.

I can't seem to figure out if this is reversible, or if once you change to Reduced Security it modifies the system in a way which would conflict with the Sealed System Volume.

Can you go back to Full Security after changing to Reduced Security and installing "System Extensions"?

Comment: When you say go back to full security, do you mean getting Apple to sign and bless the system with their keys on your system? This doesn’t make sense to me - you would erase that operating system to get back to a known stock image that Apple is willing to sign and attest to as an un-tampered with OS install.